# Force culture/multilang page when requesting non-culture page

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

On my Umbraco site, is it possible to force a redirect to the default multi language page for all pages, if someone tries to visit the page without the multi language part in it?

Here's an example:

```
website.com/en/news
website.com/da/news
```

If someone tries to visit:

```
website.com/news
```

It should redirect to the default culture page instead:

```
website.com/en/news
```

I'm guessing something like this should be rather easy (as I assume it's something most users want), but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Is /news a real page, or is all the site content underneath /en and /da?

Comment: @Tim All pages are underneath a culture.

Comment: One more quick question, where have you got your current solution code running? Is it a ContentFinder, or something else?

Comment: @Tim Hmm? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: You solution below, where are you running that code?

Comment: @Tim Inside my `Master.aspx` file (basically the master page which has `RenderBody()`).

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up making an awful fix, until I get a better "answer". It goes like this:

```
var culture = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/')[1];
if (culture != "en" && culture != "da")
{
    var shortCulture = "en";

    var languages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;

    //Just making sure
    if (languages != null && languages.Length > 0)
    {
        shortCulture = languages[0].Trim().Substring(0, 2);

        //If the culture is something like fr (French), we default back to en
        if (shortCulture != "en" && shortCulture != "da")
        {
            shortCulture = "en";
        }
    }
    Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    var url = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host;
    url += "/" + shortCulture + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    Response.RedirectPermanent(url);
}
```

So basically, if I try to request:

```
https://website.com/news
http://website.com/news
website.com/news
http://website.com/news/some-news-article/
etc. etc.
```

It will redirect. Example:

```
https://website.com/news/
|
V
https://website.com/en/news/
```

(that depends on your locale though).

Awful, awful, awful. I'm ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so in Umbraco 7, you can do this with a ContentFinder. This is something that's run as part of the content pipeline that will try and find content that Umbraco can't find by itself.

There are two parts to a content finder, the actual ContentFinder itself, and then you have to wire it in on the application startup event for Umbraco.

I've actually done something similar to what you're trying but in reverse (all my content is in /content, but I use virtual URLs like /en-en/content and map everything back in the content finder).

For information on ContentFinders, check out the documentation: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/request-pipeline/icontentfinder

Here's a gist I found that does pretty much what you're after: https://gist.github.com/alindgren/4f8e47d9b2d769137be3

The advantage of a ContentFinder is that it will only get run for content that isn't found, rather than on every page load like the solution you have now, making it more efficient!

Hope that helps!

:)